# ASP.NET MVC (2) Data Annotation Validation and UpdateModel<T> (C#)

Tags: validation, asp.net-mvc-2

So, if I want to add a new object to my database, I can write this:

```
public ActionResult Something(SomeObject Object) {
    if (ModelState.IsValid()) {
        DataContext.SomeObjects.InsertOnSubmit(Object);
        DataContext.SubmitChanges();
    };
}
```

But, how does validation get called when I want to update an object? Does `UpdateModel<T>` automatically perform the validation or do I have to do something to tell it to or do I have to do something ahead of calling `UpdateModel<t>`?

**EDIT:**

For @SLaks, so do I do something like this:

```
UpdateModel<SomeObject>(Object);

if (ModelState.IsValid()) {
    DataContext.SubmitChanges();
};
```

Or, if I'm butchering that, please show me the right way.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your original question seemed to be "how does validation get called?".

The validation is called on the object if it implements the `IDataErrorInfo` interface. `IDataErrorInfo` is implemented in the Model Binder - this happens just before the execution is passed to your Action.

So, answer in short: You don't have to tell it to do something if your using `DataAnnotations`. The validation happens automatically before you get to the Action's code. That's why `ModelState.IsValid()` returns a value - because the validation has completed.

Answer (score 1):

You should check `ModelState.IsValid()` again.